# How do I solve these integrals of wave function and operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, operators

1. First integral 
   $$\int \Psi^*({\bf r},t)\hat {\bf p} \Psi({\bf r},t)\, d^3r,$$
   where the $\Psi({\bf r},t)=e^{i({\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}-\omega t)}\,\,\,$ and $\hat {\bf p}=-i\hbar \nabla$.
2. Second one
   $$\int \Psi^*({\bf r},t)\hat {\bf p}^2 \Psi({\bf r},t)\, d^3r,$$
   where the $\Psi({\bf r},t)=e^{i({\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}-\omega t)}\,\,\,$ and $\hat {\bf p}^2=-\hbar^2 \nabla^2$.

Comment: @Nick Kidman these integrals are actually expectation value

Comment: @nabla: But the quantum state you give is an eigenstate of momentum operator.. There is no variation in momentum, then.

Comment: @Karsus Ren how about uncertainty?

Comment: @nabla: It is momentum eigenstate, then there is no momentum uncertainty.

Answer (score 3):

You want

$$\langle\hat A\rangle:=\int \Psi^*(r,t)\hat A \Psi(r,t)\, d^3r,$$

and since 
$\Psi(r,t)=e^{i(kr-wt)}$
you have

$(\Psi(r,t))^*\hat p\Psi(r,t)=\\
=(e^{i(kr-wt)})^*(-i\hbar \nabla)e^{i(kr-wt)}\\
=e^{-i(kr-wt)}(-i\hbar (ik))e^{i(kr-wt)}\\
=\hbar k,$

and so

$\langle\hat p\rangle=\\
=\int \Psi^*(r,t)\hat p \Psi(r,t)\, d^3r\\
=\int \Psi^*(r,t)(\hbar k) \Psi(r,t)\, d^3r\\
=\hbar k \int \Psi^*(r,t)1\Psi(r,t)\, d^3r\\
=\hbar k \langle\hat 1\rangle,$

and similarly

$\langle\hat p^2\rangle=(\hbar k)^2 \langle\hat 1\rangle,$

which also implies

$\langle\hat p\rangle^2=\langle\hat p^2\rangle\langle\hat 1\rangle.$

---

The usual doctrine is that the wavefunction is a normed eigenstate, i.e. 
$$\int \Psi^*(r,t)\Psi(r,t)\, d^3r=1,$$ which means $\langle\hat 1\rangle$ is equal to the number 1. The problem is that the norm of the plane wave $\Psi(r,t)=e^{i(kr-wt)}$, for which the integrand is $\Psi^*(r,t)\Psi(r,t)=e^0=1$, diverges for an integral $\int d^3r$ over an infinite volume.

I'd be tempted to just say you should define

$$\langle\hat A\rangle:=\frac{\int \Psi^*(r,t)\hat A \Psi(r,t)\, d^3r}{\int \Psi^*(r,t)\Psi(r,t)\, d^3r},$$

as then in this case $\langle\hat p\rangle:=\tfrac{\hbar k\langle\hat 1\rangle}{\langle\hat 1\rangle}$ and so the object $\langle\hat 1\rangle$ formally factors out in the computation in this case. But in general, the problem is more complicated than that. Maybe you find [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14116/whats-wrong-with-this-derivation-that-i-hbar-0) illuminating, and there are certainly others on physics.SE regarding such issues.