# Expectation value with plane waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions

Hey guys Im a little confused with the concept of plane waves and how to perform an expectation value. Let me show you by an example. Suppose you have a wave function of the form

$\psi_{\boldsymbol{p}_{0}}(x)=f(p_{0})e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol{p}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}$

where $\boldsymbol{p}_{0}=(0,0,p_{0})$ and suppose you want to perform an expectation value of the position of the particle, that is

$<x>=f^{2}(p_{0})\int\,d^{3}\boldsymbol{x}\,x\,e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol{p}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\boldsymbol{p}_{0}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}=f^{2}(p_{0})\int\,d^{3}\boldsymbol{x}\,x$

wich I think is nonsense. But if you define an arbitrary momentum vector $\boldsymbol{p}'=(p_{1}',p_{2}',p_{3}')$, and perform the transition probability

\begin{align}
\left<\psi_{\boldsymbol{p}'}(\boldsymbol{x})|\,x\,|\psi_{\boldsymbol{p}_{0}}(\boldsymbol{x})\right>&=f(p')f(p_{0})\int\,d^{3}\boldsymbol{x}\,xe^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(\boldsymbol{p}'-\boldsymbol{p}_{0})\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}=f(p')f(p_{0})\int\,d^{3}\boldsymbol{x}\left( i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{x}'}\right)e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(\boldsymbol{p}'-\boldsymbol{p}_{0})\cdot\boldsymbol{x}}= \\
&=i\hbar f(p')f(p_{0})\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{x}'}\delta^{3}(\boldsymbol{p}'-\boldsymbol{p}_{0})=-i\hbar\delta^{3}(\boldsymbol{p}'-\boldsymbol{p}_{0})\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{x}'}\left( f(p')\right)f(p_{0})
\end{align}

where I made use of the property $f(x)\delta'(x)=-f'(x)\delta(x)$. So now with my new expresion I have a meaningful result and I can evaluate for $\boldsymbol{p}'=\boldsymbol{p}_{0}$ and get a result that I wasnt able to get with the first method. What I'm doing wrong or the the second way is the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deriving the expectation of $[\hat X,\hat H]$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121653/)

Comment: Moral of this: Plane waves are *bad*.

Comment: Thanks!. So the answer is taking it between two states with different momentum and the evaluating the limit for equal momentums.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will help, a plane wave occupies ***all the space***, and the mean value of the position doesn't make much sense, but in your case is zero, because the integrand in the 1st calculus is anti-symmetrical. But this, on one condition, namely if we write the integral as

$lim _{a \to \infty} f^2(p_0) \int _a^a x d^3 x$

Otherwise it's hard to say what is the value of your integral.

The second integration is something else than the 1st one, it evaluates the matrix elements of the quantity $x$ in the base of the Fourier functions. The matrix element that is equivalent with the mean value of $x$, is the diagonal one for $p' = p_0$.

I am not sure whether you can interchange between the derivative and the integral. Up to the point where you introduced the derivative (and including that step), the integral is zero for $p' = p_0$, in the condition that we guarantee the equality in absolute value of the limits. But even if the interchange were allowed, in your before-last expression, $\delta (p' - p_0)$ for $p' = p_0$ is infinite, and you try to calculate the derivative of an infinite constant. It's not advisable to use this way.

Comment: That was my first answer when this problem came up to me. But you can tell the same about the second result? Both have to be the same when p'=p0

Comment: @TomasLibutti I am writing the answer to what you ask.

Comment: @TomasLibutti : no, I don't think that the answer is as you said, because your second way is not the same as the first. In your second calculus you evaluate matrix elements.

Comment: But the first way isnt just an evaluation of the diagonal matrix elements?

Comment: @TomasLibutti : no, I have to introduce a modification, look at it.

Comment: Im looking but I still don't see where I'm wrong or if everything is fine then how the equality between both ways came up. Thanks for your time Sofia!

Comment: @TomasLibutti : look now!

Comment: @TomasLibutti : the result of the 1st integral is zero in we guarantee that $|- \infty| = |+ \infty|$ i.e. that the two limits are equal in absolute value, although they are infinite. But, can we guarantee this?

Comment: Indeed a tricky question Sofia. I think that the "correct" way to do it is the second one. Seems more legit dont you think?

Comment: @TomasLibutti , no, it is even more unsure. Anyway, what you have in the 2nd case for $p' = p_0$ is the derivative of a constant (for $p' = p_0$ the delta is a constant, but equal to infinite). Don't use this thing, don't deal with the derivative of an infinite constant.

Answer (score 0):

> wich I think is nonsense

Formally, shouldn't the 2nd equation be

$$\langle x \rangle = \frac{\langle\psi_{\mathbf p_0}|\hat x|\psi_{\mathbf p_0}\rangle}{\langle\psi_{\mathbf p_0}|\psi_{\mathbf p_0}\rangle} = \frac{f^2(p_0)\int d\mathbf x^3 x}{f^2(p_0)\int d\mathbf x^3} = \frac{\int d\mathbf x^3 x}{\int d\mathbf x^3} = \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\int_{-\tau}^{\tau} d\mathbf x^3 x}{\int_{-\tau}^{\tau} d\mathbf x^3} = \lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty}\frac{0}{2\tau} = 0 $$