# Can the momentum eigenstates be non-orthogonal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, potential-energy, fourier-transform, discrete

Consider the Hilbert space of a particle, whose position domain is confined to $q\in[0,1]$ (e.g. a particle in a box with unit width). Using 
$$
1=\int_0 ^1 dq |q\rangle\langle q|
$$
and the position representation of the discrete momentum eigenstates
$$
\langle q | p_n\rangle=e^{i\pi n q},
$$
inserting the above identity operator and integrating leads to the scalar product 
$$
\langle p_n|p_m\rangle=\frac{(-1)^{m-n}-1}{i\pi(m-n)}\neq\delta_{nm}.
$$

This would mean that the eigenbasis of a physical observable is not orthogonal.
Is there an error in my derivation, and if not, how can this be understood physically?

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with the Dirac notation. Just your $\int\mathrm{d}p\lvert p \rangle \langle p \rvert$ needs to become a $\sum_n \lvert p_n \rangle \langle p_n \lvert$, and the corresponding Dirac deltas become Kroneckers, and so on. It is *really* not an issue of the notation, but of you using states that aren't there - there are no continuous momenta here, so you can't integrate over them.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I really got that point. In my question I also consider to use the discrete basis already. The point is that using $\sum_n|p_n\rangle\langle p_n|$ still does not resolve the problem with $\langle p_n | p_m\rangle\neq\delta_{nm}$. This calculation is independent of the momentum projector.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The only way I see for the missing factor $2$ would be to use the momentum eigenvalues $p_n=n2\pi \hbar$ instead of $p_n=n\pi\hbar$. However, for mass $2m=1$, the energy spectrum is $E_n=(n\pi\hbar)^2$ and $E_n=p_n^2$, so everything should be correct.

Comment: I am sorry for antagonizing you. Have a look at [this old question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121653/50583) and/or [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907069). You correctly observe that the momentum states are not proper eigenvectors, so taking their scalar product is, deep down, simply not possible (because they belong to the larger space in the [Gelfand tripel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) here, probably).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This would mean that the eigenbasis of a physical observable is not orthogonal. Is there an error in my derivation, and if not, how can this be understood physically?

The set of eigenfunctions of $\hat p$ in the sense
$$
\hat{p}\phi = p\phi
$$
is sure to be orthogonal if they belong to a subset of $L^2((0,1))$ on which the operator $\hat{p}$ is symmetric, meaning

$$
\int_0^1 \phi_1^* \hat{p} \phi_2dq = \int_0^1 (\hat{p}\phi_1)^* \phi_2 dq 
$$
for any two functions of the subset.

The momentum operator $\hat{p} = -i\hbar \partial/\partial q$ on $(0,1)$ is symmetric only for subset of eigenfunctions $e^{ipq/\hbar}$ that obey favorable boundary condition (with the right value of $p$ - see Ruslan's answer) this subset of eigenfuncitons is orthogonal and forms a basis of the subset.

For most of the eigenfunctions $e^{iqp/\hbar}$, however, the operator $\hat{p}$ is not symmetric and there is no orthogonality.

Comment: Thanks, this was the missing piece I needed! Let me remark, that on an algebraic level it becomes already clear that the $|p_n\rangle$ belong to a "larger" Hilbert space, as their position representation $\langle q | p_n\rangle=e^{i\pi nq}$ violates the box boundary conditions. Thus, they are not orthogonal in the same way, as two orthogonal vectors $u,v,\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are not necessarily when projected some lower-dimensional manifold.

Comment: I've improved the answer after I read Ruslan's mention of periodic boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is be conserved iff the Hamiltonian has translational symmetry. Usual boundary conditions such as homogeneous Dirichlet or Neumann conditions don't allow for such symmetry. But there still are specific conditions, which do allow the Hamiltonian to have translational symmetry on the bounded domain: [Born—von Karman boundary conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93von_Karman_boundary_condition).

Thus in the box $q\in[0,1]$ the momentum operator $\hat p=-i\partial_q$ is self-adjoint if you use Born—von Karman boundary conditions, i.e. conditions of periodicity of wavefunction:
$$\psi(0)=\psi(1),$$
$$\psi'(0)=\psi'(1).$$

Then it has a set of orthonormal eigenfunctions

$$\phi_p(q)=e^{ipq}$$

with $p=2\pi n.$

Any other boundary conditions don't give you orthogonal eigenfunctions. In fact, the second condition is extraneous because the operator is first order derivative, so that eigenequation $\hat p\phi(q)=p\phi(q)$ is a first order differential equation, which has only one free parameter. This is one of the reasons why you can't impose usual two boundary conditions like in Dirichlet or Neumann case.

Comment: True, but what reason is there to assume $\psi(0)=\psi(1)$? The two points refer to a very different state, after all.

Comment: @JánLalinský this is needed to ensure periodicity, which in turn is needed for translational symmetry, so that momentum could be conserved. Without translational symmetry there's no chance to have states with definite momentum.