# The momentum representation of $x$ and $ [x,p]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, dirac-delta-distributions

To deduce the momentum representation of $[x,p]$, we can see one paradom

$$<p|[x,p]|p>=iℏ$$

$$<p|[x,p]|p>=<p|xp|p>−<p|px|p>=p<p|x|p>−p<p|x|p>=0$$

Why? If we deduce the momentum representation of $x$, we obtain
$<p|x|p>=i\hbar \frac{\partial \delta (p'-p)}{\partial p'}|_{p'=p}$. This value is not definite. So, why two uncertain values can obtained a certain value $i\hbar$? In addition, the $x$ should be replace by $i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial p}$. Then the eigenvalue p can't extract. However, if we consider $i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial p}$ to act on the bra, not the ket, then the eigenvalue p can be extracted. Is anything wrong here?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14116/