# Uncertainty principle when in position (or momentum) eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Suppose we want to calculate the expectation value
$$\langle x|[\hat{x},\hat{p}]|x\rangle,$$
where $|x\rangle$ is an position eigenstate, so that $\hat{x}|x\rangle=x|x\rangle$ and $\langle x|\hat{x} = x\langle x|.$
If we 'forget' for a moment the canonical commutation relation, we get
$$\langle x|\hat{x}\hat{p}|x\rangle-\langle x|\hat{p}\hat{x}|x\rangle = x\langle x|\hat{p}|x\rangle- x\langle x|\hat{p}|x\rangle = 0,$$
which, according to the generalized uncertainty principle
$$\Delta x\Delta p \geq\left|\frac {\langle-i[\hat{x},\hat{p}]\rangle} {2}\right|,$$
means that when we are on a position (or momentum) eigenvector we can measure simultaneously (as accurately as we want) position and momentum (!?).

What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Position eigenvector is not a physical state

Comment: $\langle x'|[\hat x,\hat p]|x\rangle = i\hbar\delta(x-x')$. You are evaluating this at $x=x'$.

Comment: Expanding it out doesn't really help: $\langle x'|[\hat x, \hat p]|x\rangle = -i(x' - x)\frac{d}{dx'}\delta(x - x')$. The $\delta'(x-x')$ is going to infinity as the $x-x'$ is going to zero...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14116/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher has presumably taught you the way out of all these
pseudoparadoxes: Consider Gaussian states of vanishing width. Instead of doing that, effectively hijacking your question to something more interesting, I will remind you of the erroneous way you are multiplying 0 to infinities *of different orders*!

The short answer is that, technically (physics aside: there is little physics in $|x\rangle$ unnormalizable states!), $\Delta x=0$, indeed, but $\Delta p=\infty$, to satisfy Robertson's formal inequality. You are effectively pleading for a formal way to bypass your technical mistake ("you get"; no you don't!). Take $\hbar=1$ w.l.o.g.

For starters, remind yourself of the identity
$$
\epsilon \delta(\epsilon)=0, ~~~~\leadsto \\
\epsilon \partial_\epsilon \delta(\epsilon)= -\delta(\epsilon).
$$

You are effectively considering matrix elements implicitly under the *final step* operation $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$. Specifically, evaluating the canonical commutator,
$$
\langle x+\epsilon|[\hat x, \hat p]|x\rangle = i\delta (\epsilon), 
$$
divergent.

The same follows from your formal pathway,
$$
\langle x+\epsilon|[\hat x, \hat p]|x\rangle =(x+\epsilon)\langle x+\epsilon|  \hat p |x\rangle - x \langle x+\epsilon|  \hat p |x\rangle=\epsilon  \langle x+\epsilon|  \hat p |x\rangle\\
 =-i\epsilon \int \!\! dy~~ \langle x+\epsilon|y\rangle \partial _y \langle y|x\rangle= -i\epsilon \partial_\epsilon \delta (\epsilon)= i\delta(\epsilon),
$$
by dint of $\hat p=-i \int \!\! dy~~ |y\rangle \partial _y \langle y|$.

So, taking the limit, you indeed find  a divergent
$$
\Delta x \Delta p \geq \delta (0)/2~ . 
$$

(You can take a further derivative in the leading identity,
$\partial_\epsilon^2\delta (\epsilon) = {2\over \epsilon^2} \delta (\epsilon)$.)