# What is $\left<x\right|\hat x\hat p-\hat p\hat x\left|x\right>$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator, dirac-delta-distributions

This is simple question, but I don't know how to do it.

$\left<x\right|\hat x\hat p-\hat p\hat x\left|x\right>=?$,

I can solve it in two ways.

One of them is
$$\left<x\right|\hat x\hat p-\hat p\hat x\left|x\right>=\left<x\right|i \hslash\left|x\right>=i\hslash\delta(x,x)$$

The other is
$$\left<x\right|\hat x\hat p-\hat p\hat x\left|x\right>=\left<x\right|(x-x)\hat p\left|x\right>=0$$

In my opinion, this problem comes from Dirac delta function.

Comment: @doublefelix It's a duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769879/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's wrong with this derivation that $i\hbar = 0$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14116/)