# What went wrong in the following calculation of $\langle p'|[x,p]|p'\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, commutator, dirac-delta-distributions

We know that $$[x,p]=i\hbar. $$

Consider now the diagonal element in the momentum representation, $$\langle p'|[x,p]|p'\rangle=i\hbar\langle p'|p'\rangle=i\hbar\delta(0).$$

But the LHS = $$\langle p'|xp-px|p'\rangle=\langle p'|xp'-p'x|p'\rangle=p'(\langle p'|x|p'\rangle-\langle p'|x|p'\rangle)=0.$$

What went wrong?

Comment: This is incredibly important for QM, fixing a lot of other stuff, and known under [Stone-von Neumann theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) Basically, the part where you did the subtraction, it was infinity minus infinity leaving behind an infinity rather than zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14116/2451

Comment: Consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong step was in assuming that those expressions are well-defined in the first place.

The "generalized" bras/kets $|p\rangle$ and $|x\rangle$ are not true members of the Hilbert space, and expressions like $\langle p'| (\ldots)|p'\rangle$ are inherently ill-defined, regardless of what's in the middle. When working with these rather singular objects and the delta functions to which they are intimately related, you **must** have different labels on the bra and ket, e.g.
$$\langle p|p'\rangle = \delta(p-p')$$

Moreover, the expression $[X,P] = i\hbar \mathbb I$ is not actually true, because the right-hand side can act on any bra or ket while the left-hand side can act only on a limited domain. Treating this as a strict and literal equality can lead to some technical issues such as the one you are currently running into.

---

For perfectly good reasons, physicists often dispense with the rigorous treatment of distributions, generalized vectors, and rigged Hilbert spaces in favor of a more practical and down-to-Earth approach to quantum mechanics. However, this comes at the cost of having to deal with some opaque, seemingly ad-hoc rules like these to keep you out of the trap that you have fallen into.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have (as mentioned in comments and @J. Murray) is that none of the things you are evaluating are defined. We instead calculate $\langle p'| [ X , P ] | p \rangle$. This is manipulated as
$$
\langle p' | [ X , P ] | p \rangle = \langle p' | X P - P X | p \rangle = ( p - p' ) \langle p' | X | p \rangle
$$
We now use the fact that
$$
X | p \rangle = - i \hbar \frac{d}{dp} | p \rangle
$$
Then,
$$
\langle p' | [ X , P ] | p \rangle = - i \hbar  ( p - p' ) \frac{d}{dp} \langle p' | p \rangle = - i \hbar  ( p - p' ) \frac{d}{dp}\delta ( p - p' ) 
$$
Now you see why you get infinity if you simply set $p=p'$ without careful consideration. This result is consistent with the commutator since
$$
\langle p' | [ X , P ] | p \rangle = i \hbar \langle p' | p \rangle = i\hbar \delta ( p - p')
$$
I'll leave it to you to verify that both results are equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Prahar. Yes, using integration by parts I see that $\delta(p-p')=-(p-p')\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\delta(p-p')$. I naively thought that $\lim_{p'\to p}[(p-p')\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\delta(p-p')]=0$, probably because $\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\delta(p-p')$ can be thought of as an odd function of $p$.